# Rest Data Ingestion to Data lake

Tags: java, rest, apache-kafka

I have 1000's of rest web service.
Requirement
Standard way to ingest data to data lake?
Full Load and CDC and stream data also.
Data to be loaded to kafka topic without duplicatuion

Answer (score 0):

Your web services could use the Kafka Producer API to send data to Kafka directly, as well as make use of the Kafka Streams API if they want to do stream processing with the data. Kafka Connect API is how you stream data from other sources (databases etc) into Kafka topics.

From Kafka, you can use Kafka Connect's HDFS connector to stream data from topics into HDFS/S3 etc.

Comment: Web services are not owned by us.Its provided by third party vendors.We need to access the Rest endpoints and push data to data lake and kafka.

Comment: So my answer still stands in terms of getting it into a data lake (Kafka Connect HDFS/S3 connectors). To get it into Kafka I would look at the Kafka Connect API and writing a connector that pulls from these web service endpoints.

Comment: Is there a connector(opensource) to pull data from Rest and format it and push to kafka,so that next time accessing the same serve and pushing data should avoid duplicates also

Comment: I'm not aware of one, you'd probably need to write it. You can find a dev guide here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html